# CircleCI terraform destroy fails?

Tags: circleci

I am new to CircleCI and trying to implement a simple workflow to apply and delete my terraform infrastructure using the terraform orb. This is my `.circleci/config.yml` file :-

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  terraform: circleci/terraform@3.1
jobs:
  deploy_infrastructure:
    executor: terraform/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - terraform/init
      - terraform/validate
      - terraform/plan
      - terraform/apply
      - terraform/destroy
workflows:
  deploy_infrastructure:
    jobs:
      - deploy_infrastructure
```

I am able to create the infrastructure but as soon as it gets to `destroy`, it fails with the following error :-

```
Error: Module not installed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1:
│    1: module "vpc" {
│ 
│ This module is not yet installed. Run "terraform init" to install all modules required by this configuration
```

I even added `terraform/init` step before the `terraform/destroy` step and it still fails with the same error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably a bug in the Orb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version: '2.1'
jobs:
  init:
    docker:
      - image: hashicorp/terraform
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: terraform init
      - run: terraform plan
      - run: terraform apply -auto-approve
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: .
          paths:
            - .
  hold:
    docker:
      - image: hashicorp/terraform
    steps:
      - run: echo "Placeholder"

  destroy:
    docker:
      - image: hashicorp/terraform
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: .
      - run: terraform destroy -auto-approve 

workflows:
  test:
    jobs:
      - init
      - hold:
          type: approval
          requires:
            - init
      - destroy:
          requires:
            - hold
```

This worked!!!